# How to do this removal of list in java?

Tags: java, list

I have customers list say that list will always have 5 rows i have to remove the last three rows in the iteration,

```
for (Customer cust: oh.getCustomer()) {  
// Check the size of order and remove the last three rows                   
}
```

Any suggestion how this can be done??

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/

Comment: The sole line of code you wrote doesn't seem to make sense. Would oh.getCustomer() return an iterable collection of customers ?

Comment: you didnot tell total number of customer list.can you elaborate more about your question?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a `for` loop instead of `foreach`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < oh.getCustomer().size(); i++) {
    if (i >= oh.getCustomer().size()-3) {
        break;
    }
}
```

(or something like this)

OR you can remove last 3 items using this method: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

How about getting the subset of the list ?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean?

```
List<Customer> customers = oh.getCustomer();
for(int i = -1; i >= -3 && customer.size()>0;i--)
    oh.removeCustomer(customers.get(customer.size() - i));
```

if customers were modifiable, which it really shouldn't be, you can do this.

```
customers.subList(Math.max(0, customers.size()-3), customers.size()).clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `oh.getCustomer()` is a `java.util.list`, you can try something like:

```
List<Customer> customers = oh.getCustomer();
customers.subList(2, customers.size()).clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

**lot of way to do this.**

simple as you know that list is order by index.

**list will always have 5 rows**

you know that list will always contains 5 elements.

then you don't need to use for loop, create a `newList` and get the first `two` elements from your existence list and add it to the newly created list.

```
List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();

customerList.add(oldList.get(0))

customerList.add(oldList.get(1))
```